# adb over WiFi for Pico i.MX7D

Tags: adb, android-things

I have not been able to connect to the Pico i.MX7D using adb over WiFI (USB debugging works without problems) I get connection refused.

I can get it to work by connecting using adb shell over cable and then:

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

But this is not persisted after a reboot, so it isn't really useful.

Android has an option on settings to turn network adb on and off, but that setting is not appearing on Android Things. Is there a way to enable it?

The reason for wanting adb over WiFi is that once you have the board inside a contraption, it is easier to connect over WiFi than by cable (which is already used for power).

Comment: Thanks Alex! I will try that solution and update it if it works.

Comment: Using "setprop persist.adb.tcp.port 5555" worked. I just needed to do "su" first.